# How do I use the jqm.page.params.js plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am working with jquery mobile and I am trying to pass variables within the same page.

```
<a href="page2.html?var1=foo&var2=bar">link1</a>
<a href="page2.html?var1=something&var2=bbq">link2</a>
```

After clicking on the link the page will be placed into the DOM.  I understand that I will have to reload the page to allow for the new variables to be applied, but I have not been successfull doing this with the:

```
$.mobile.changePage("page2.html", {reloadPage : true,});
```

When the page loads I am using the following:

```
$(document).delegate('#page2','pageinit', function(){           

   $.mobile.changePage("page2.html", {reloadPage : true});          

});
```

The above code will just take the page in a forever loop, which is obviously not what I want.  I tried to take the changePage out side of the pageinit, but the reason for needing it inside the pageinit is for the back button to work.  So then I thought that that maybe I could get the variables from the url, so I tried the following with the use of the [jqm.page.params.js](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/blob/master/page-params/jqm.page.params.js):

```
$(document).delegate('#page2','pageinit', function(){           

   if ($.mobile.pageData && $.mobile.pageData.proj_id){
      console.log("Parameter var1=" + $.mobile.pageData.var1);//does not print at all.
   }

   console.log("Parameter obj =" + $.mobile.pageData); // prints NULL           

});
```

I found in the documentation a link to the plugin which is suppose to allow you to use the parameters in the url called [jqm.page.params.js](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/blob/master/page-params/jqm.page.params.js) but there is no examples on how to use this plugin.

Is there anyone here that knows how to use this plugin?  Or is there a better way on passing variables when you are on the same page linking to the same page but with different variables?

Answer (score 2):

I think `pageinit` is too early so the params aren't parsed then.  Try `pagebeforeshow` for your listener.

[See the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238762/passing-parameters-to-a-page-id-in-jquery-mobile).