# jquery mobile page change keeps same query string

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am changing pages from a listview in a jquery mobile application like  and  when I select the first link I have it set up to show an alert of the querystring hello (for testing). It works fine for the first one, but when I click the second link it still shows hello, not helloagain. Is there some sort of cache setting I can disable so that it does not cache on that page and shows what was previously set? I have tried data-dom-cache="false" option on the page and I had no luck, thanks for any help.

Comment: Need sample code (or at least more details... but probably sample code) or this is impossible to answer.

Comment: This helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238762/passing-parameters-to-a-page-id-in-jquery-mobile