# jQuery Mobile how to load different javascript code

Tags: jquery-mobile

Could not find a better title but will explain my problem here.
I have a jquery mobile app with a login page.
After logging in an API call determines which databaseversion the user/customer has.
Since all logic is going by API calls to the user/customer database.
So after logging in there basically is a need for a different js codebase.
In other words a different html head is needed e.g:

Login page

```
<head><script src="app/scripts/version_all.js"></script></head>
```

After login

```
<head><script src="app/scripts/Versions/version1_1.js"></script></head>
```

My jqm has multipage template setup.
Can anybody give some pointers to solve this in an elegant way? 
Should I work for example with page refresh or should I inject code ?

---

Okay, I cheered to early.
This is the important part of my index.php

```
<?php if (!empty($_REQUEST['dbversion'])){ ?>
 <script src="app/scripts/Versions/combined<?php echo $_POST['dbversion'];>.js"></script>   
<?php } else { ?>
 <script src="app/scripts/Versions/combined.js"></script>   
<?php } ?>
```

And here is my page redirect:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#loginpage',{
         type: "get",
         data: {dbversion:"DB11"}
    }
    );
```

Since #loginpage is not a url the data argument is not picked up.
When I change it to

```
$.mobile.changePage('index.php#loginpage',{
         type: "get",
         data: {dbversion:"DB11"}
    }
    );
```

I get a blank page because #loginpage is not picked up

Comment: after successful login use `$.mobile.changePage("url", { reloadPage: true });` or `window.location.href = "url";`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. How can I provide the different script src after refresh ? Since index.html is static html ?

Comment: Never mind, got it. Changed index.html to index.php so I can read url params

Comment: Sorry I have no rep to give you upvote

Comment: it's ok, I've done nothing ;) post an answer.

Comment: I finally got it all working with this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238762/passing-parameters-to-a-page-id-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: note that this works only on jQM 1.2